# True HiDPI in IntelliJ 15

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I used to use IntelliJ 14 with the -Dhidpi=true flag in the vmoptions file and didn't have any problems with the scaling. I've just upgraded to 15 and it features "True HiDPI" but it doesn't seem to work on my Surface Pro 3. I chose to import my options from my previous build but I've checked the new vmoptions file and that flag wasn't copied over. The JetBrains site mentions that the flag isn't required anymore anyway. I've looked through the settings dialogs and the only relevant option seems to be the anti-aliasing settings which are defaulted to subpixel (sounds fine to me). Anyone have an idea how to get back to the 14-era scaling? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing "Override the default fonts by..." setting in Appearance & Behavior => Appearance tab. It scaled the menu and icons accordingly for me.

Comment: that helped, though i'm not sure if that should be something i need to be doing considering it's marked "not recommended".

Comment: Whether recommended or not - manually doubling the size of standard fonts is imho not a very good solution compared to observing a system wide scaling setting (as used typically on Windows boxes)

Comment: Doesn't work for me (2017 1.2). Fonts are scaled, but icons are still tiny.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, in addition to the setting in

> Appearance & Behavior > Appearance

tab, the following font settings have to be changed, too:

- Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font
- Editor > Colors & Fonts > Console Font (Button `Apply editor font setting`)

I haven't found a clear and official recipe to get IntelliJ running correctly on a High DPI screen yet (and have also had a support request running a while ago on which I was repeatedly asked to provide new screen shots using new EAP releases), but I think this is the closest you can get with the IntelliJ 15.

Update 2017-20-17:

It looks like JetBrains has noticed that some people have problems with high-DPI screens. There is a new article (with discussion) that suggests some remedies (I haven't tested them yet, as my current setup is more or less usable):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001260010